# How to insert 3 columns after each column with a certain header?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet where the first column header is "Item Number", second column header (column B) is "365 day sales", and the next 1-50 column headers are "Next_Item_X" where X is number 1-50.

I want to insert 3 columns **after** each "Next_Item_X" column with the headers "365_Day_Sales_X", "Total_On_Hand_X", and "Open_PO_QTY_X" where X is the same number as the X in the column header it was inserted after.

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I did not receive an answer to this, or my last question which was blocked for not being focused, I will share the workaround I came up with.

After selecting the last column I want to run the code on, this code will insert 3 columns with column headers after the selected column.  It will do this as many times as I tell it to with an input box, moving backwards (Column E to Column A for example).  It also inserts formulas into the 2nd row of each added column and autofills the formulas to the last row.

I was trying to find if someone had a way to do this without the need for an input box but this is working very well and I'm very happy with the result:

```
Sub 365_Insert_Columns()

LastRow = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

MsgBox "Select last column to insert after before running macro."

I2 = Selection.Column + 1

I3 = InputBox("Enter number of columns to insert", "Insert Columns")
If I3 = vbNullString Then
    MsgBox "Macro Cancelled."
    Exit Sub
End If

For I = 0 To I3 - 1

S = Right(Cells(1, (I2 - 1) - I).Value, Len(Cells(1, Selection.Column).Value) - 5)
rngS = Replace(Cells(2, (I2 - 1) - I).Address, "$", "")

Columns(I2 - I).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Cells(1, I2 - I).Value = "365_Day_Sales_" & S
Cells(2, I2 - I).Value = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(" & rngS & ",'365_Sales_Pivot'!A:B,2,0), 0)"
Cells(2, I2 - I).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, I2 - I), Cells(LastRow, I2 - I))
Columns(I2 - I).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Cells(1, I2 - I).Value = "On_Hand_" & S
Cells(2, I2 - I).Value = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(" & rngS & ",'Total_On_Hand'!A:B,2,0), 0)"
Cells(2, I2 - I).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, I2 - I), Cells(LastRow, I2 - I))
Columns(I2 - I).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Cells(1, I2 - I).Value = "Open_PO_QTY_" & S
Cells(2, I2 - I).Value = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(" & rngS & ",'Open_PO_QTY'!A:B,2,0), 0)"
Cells(2, I2 - I).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, I2 - I), Cells(LastRow, I2 - I))

Next I

Call AutoBorders
Call AutoFitCells

End Sub
```